# What is the Reason Korean Queen Heo Hwang Ok assumed to come from Ayodhya?

Tags: korean

When Most of the Proofs Direct Queen Heo Hwang ok came from Tamilnadu(Ayutha - Kanyakumari). Why its assumed she came from Ayodhya?